# Encrypt file on FreeBSD

Tags: encryption, freebsd, gnupg

I can't get `mcrypt` to work on a FreeBSD server (`[Bus error 10]`). GPG doesn't work, it says it cannot open `/dev/tty`.

Any ideas?

Also, I kind need to be able to decrypt the file on (Ubuntu) Linux.  I tried `enigma`/`crypt` on FreeBSD, and then when I copy the file to Linux, `crypt` cannot decrypt it.

Comment: Regarding gpg, do you use gpg in a script or from a GUI? There is a "--no-tty" option that might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For symmetric encryption you could use `enc(1)` which is part of openssl. To encrypt a file with aes256-xts cipher:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-xts -in foo.txt -out foo.txt.enc
```

And to decrypt it:

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-xts -in foo.txt.enc -out foo.txt
```

Pretty easy huh?

One other neat feature is that it supports `base64` which means it'll use only ascii characters. Just add `-a` to the list of arguments and then look at the encrypted file.

`enc(1)` is a versatile program. I use it often when I quickly want to copy a file or a small compressed tar archive from one terminal screen to the other, I simply *only* use `base64`.

Let's say I want to quickly copy a directory `/home/drumfire/test` which contains a few files, and can't use `scp` or other tools. It's trivial to run this through a compression program and encode it:

```
tar cf - /home/drumfire/test | xz -9ec | openssl enc -a
```

The result is a blob of ascii text. I select to copy it, and then on the target system I can simply do:

```
openssl enc -a -d | xz -dc | tar xvf -
```

In this case `Openssl` will wait for input from `stdin`. so I hit Shift+Insert which pastes the text, then I press press CTRL+D two times and voila, it extracts.

Neat stuff. B-)